# Terrible wifi in a new apartment

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm trying to improve the wifi in my new apartment but have run out of ideas.

Basically the problem manifests as follows:

For the first 10 seconds after connecting, its all good, good signal speed and quality.

Then the signal quality drops to 4 bars (out of 5) and the speed starts changing erratically between 6.5Mbps and 300Mbps. The actual user experience is pretty awful, you get 1 second of internet every 10 seconds or so, during that 1 second you got all the speed in the world but for most of the time there is no internet at all. I should also note that it doesn't disconnect but stays connected in this crappy fashion the entire time.

So first I checked the channels, I'm sitting in channel 1 alone, there are 2 other networks in the building at channel 6 and 11, AFAIK thats about as perfect as this situation can get. Also, inSSIDer reports a signal strength of -49dBm which should be pretty good, right?

Then I checked different client devices, my laptop, phone, 2 different types of usb wifi adapters and a pcie adapter all behave the same way.

Then I tried different hotspot devices, 3 different wifi routers, a software hotspot from my desktop, a hotspot from my laptop, all the same.

I also tried 5Ghz but only between one wifi router and my laptop since those 2 are the only ones that support it, no improvement.

It seems its just this apartment, I can't get a good connection even if the receiving device is right next to the sending one.

Now about the apartment - its semi underground in a pretty old building, the outside walls are natural stone of some sort, the inside walls are mostly drywall but also a few made of reinforced concrete. I  get good reception on my phone even in rooms closest to the center of the building, also good 4G.

Also yes, my internet is perfectly fine, I use a wired connection on my desktop.

So.. my current theory is that there is an interdimensional rift in my apartment that specifically sucks away all wifi signals. Does anyone got a better one?

Comment: Do you live near any military radar sites or next to any radio antennae?  Have you tried replacing the router?

Comment: Nope, its a suburban setting in a medium sized city, nothing out of the ordinary. Also my last apartment was just 500m away from this one and had no problems there. And yes, I tried 3 different routers.

Comment: Okay. So that rules out the device and brings it back to local area. Cordless phones and faulty microwaves can also cause interference with WiFi. Is the router particularly close to any other electrical items?

Comment: @Mokubai Its normally close to my desktop computer, I tried moving it around the room and the room next to this one, no difference. I also discovered something odd though, when I ping the router with -t flag an odd pattern emerges - 1 packet has ping of <2ms and the next one is always around 1000ms, over and over.

Comment: Did you *try* the other channels or just look with inSSIDer? inSSIDer can only see Wi-Fi, not Bluetooth or baby monitors or microwave ovens or wireless security cams, etc. If you haven’t actually tried channel 11, try it. If that makes the problem go away and you’re still curious, consider buying a Wi-Spy or other spectrum analyzer to see *all* the RF energy in the band.

Comment: What's the model of router you are using?